# BFGS method: Solving a quadratic function. How many iterations?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I would like to know the theoretical number of iterations for the BFGS method to minimise a quadratic function.

From this source: http://www.aptech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/qnewton.pdf

On page 2 line 4 it says that we only need a single step to solve a quadratic equation.

From this source: http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Numerical_Optimization.pdf

p210 theorem 8.4 it says that: (i) The iterates converge to the solution in at most n iterations.

So which is it? If anyone could offer some clarity that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

On page 2 line 4 they are referring to Newton's method, not BFGS.

Newton's method minimizes a quadratic function in one iteration. Quasi-Newton methods do not.

Comment: But if I have n=3 and it is solved in 1 iteration that is not a completely unrealistic result to get?

Comment: @CMACK  Do you mean that your $n=3$ example was solved in one iteration by Newton's method or by the BFGS method? If it was Newton's method, then one iteration to minimize a quadratic function is correct. If it was BFGS, the result seems suspicious to me, but I would have to look at it more closely.

Comment: Yes my $n=3$ example

Comment: @CMACK What happens for larger problems? Did you implement both Newton's method and the BFGS method yourself?

Comment: Yes I implemented them both but my BFGS method claims that my matrix dimensions do not agree when I use the BFGS method and so I asked someone to look at my code. He gave me back code which I believe is nonsense but he claims it is correct and that my BFGS method converges after one iteration. Although it has just occured to me now that if $n=3$ I could quickly just work it out by hand!